# PHP - is this PHP or CentOS, Red hat enterprise linux bug? When doing php://output it fails to output under Red hat linux but works in other OS

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos, phpexcel, rhel

I have this excel file creator libraries ( http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ ) which is working in my Ubuntu to make `xlsx` files.

But when putting this working version, in main server ( CentOS and RHEL 6.4 ) cause the file not to be shown via `$objWriter->save('php://output');` and also do not throw any error in log files.

Simply fails to create the file and dump in the browser. (trying under ZF1 , PHP5)

```
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  .....

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  ob_end_clean();

  $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Compare php.ini configuration settings between the two servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) mentioned what requires ( https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/01-Getting-Started.md )

> Software requirements
>
> The following software is required to develop using PHPExcel:
>
> PHP version 5.2.0 or newer PHP extension php_zip enabled
>   [^phpzip_footnote] PHP extension php_xml enabled PHP extension php_gd2
>   enabled (if not compiled in)

2) so in server i reinstalled all those and following

```
$ yum remove php-xml
$ yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Setting up Install Process
Package php-xml-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

3) then restarted the httpd

it Works!